# Debugging Google Map V2 can't connect Google Service

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm testing com.example.mapdemo, I have put my Android Google Map Key API in the manifest file, then I registered the SHA1 key generated with keytool in Eclipse in my API project (Google API Console), it seems everything would have to run nicely but during runtime logcat says the app can't connect to Google Services, so, the map doesn't load, just the + and - zoom buttons. Considering this, I have two questions:

1. When the certificate is generated , I have to put the same author name as my google account?
2. If I am debugging the project (not publishing), it is built with **default** debug keystore and SHA1, am I right? so, google doesn't recognize it and the app will never connect to google service.

Am I right or the issue has nothing to do with my thoughts?. Someone could give me any ideas to solve this? Thanks.  :(

Comment: have you referred to the google play services library?

Comment: It's not clear with which key did you signed the app(own key or the key for the debug certificate).

Comment: I think I'm going to answer both question at once. I've just **exported** the project generating my own key (SHA1) and registered it in my google API's, then I've installed via adb command and guess what ... yes !!! it runs nicely. I think in debug mode the app is  signed with the default SHA1 key, but if when it is exported, then it is signed with the SHA1 key properly that google recognizes. [Here](http://joe.freevar.com/build_pref.jpg) is my build preference, must I change something in here to avoid exportation each time I want to test the project?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section on this page "Displaying certificate information":
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key

Specifically, see the "Displaying the debug certificate fingerprint" section.

When you launch the Android app using Eclipse (i.e., just click the green "play button"), it is signed using the default debug keystore.  So, you can just whitelist the SHA-1 fingerprint of the debug keystore via the Google API Console as well, so you can see the map without needing to export the app and sign with your release key.  You can add multiple SHA-1 fingerprints, followed by the app package name, in the Google API Console, just put each one on its own line.

Here's a brief excerpt from the above docs on how to find the fingerprint for your debug key:

> - Locate your debug keystore file. The file name is debug.keystore, and is created the first time you build your project. By default, it is stored in the same directory as your Android Virtual Device (AVD) files:
>
>   - OS X and Linux: ~/.android/
>   - Windows Vista and Windows 7: C:\Users\your_user_name.android\
>
> If you are using Eclipse with ADT, and you're not sure where your debug keystore is located, you can select Windows > Prefs > Android > Build to check the full path, which you can then paste into a file explorer to locate the directory containing the keystore.
>
> - List the SHA-1 fingerprint.
>
>   - For Linux or OS X, open a terminal window and enter the following:
>       `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
>   - For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:
>       `keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
>
> You should see output similar to this:
>
> ```
> `Alias name: androiddebugkey`
> ```
>
> ...
>         `SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75`
>
> The line that begins SHA1 contains the certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint. The fingerprint is the sequence of 20 two-digit hexadecimal numbers separated by colons.

Then just whitelist it like you did the release cert SHA-1.

Comment: hahaha I read your first three lines of your answer and I thought I deserve a very painful torture. Of course your are absolutely right!, Sean.